# Two images next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place quote1.jpg next to yoda.png, but no matter where I place the div class it ends up somewhere else. First it was on top of the header now it is covering up Yoda. When you hover your mouse over Yoda it is supposed to show his quote but instead it shows the quote.jpg. All I am trying to do is place the quote.jpg next to Yoda.

```css
.header {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: cursive, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', 
    sans-serif ;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    }

p {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    }

  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;  
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }
  
  .container:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  
  .container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 2;
  }
  
  .text {
    background-color: rgb(13, 53, 228);
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
  }

/* No matter what I do I cannot 
place the quote1.jpg in the correct place */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Here We Go!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "header">
     <h1>I Am Tying Hard To Learn Html</h1>
     <p>"Do Or Do Not There Is No Try"</p>
     </div> 
    <div class= "container">
            <img src="yoda.png" alt="Yoda" 
            class= "image" style = "width:50%">
    <div class="text">That right, you got.  
      Herh herh herh.
      <div class ="middle">
          <img src="quote1.jpg" alt="quote">
    </div>
              
        </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML Code]

---

[image: CSS Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use javascript or jquery to implement what you intend.
Here is a sample code:

```
.header {
background: black;
color: white;
font-family: cursive, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', 
sans-serif ;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

p {
background-color: blanchedalmond;
font-size: 26px;
color: black;
opacity: 1;
}


.image {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
transition: .5s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}


.text {
display:block;
opacity: 0;
background-color: rgb(13, 53, 228);
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
padding: 16px 32px;
}

.flex-container {
display: flex;   
flex-flow:row wrap;    
}

  .block{  
  display: block;    
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100px;     
 }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
     scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Here We Go!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function show() {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];            
            element.classList.toggle("open");

        }

        function hide() {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0];
            element.classList.toggle("open");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>I Am Tying Hard To Learn Html</h1>
        <p>"Do Or Do Not There Is No Try"</p>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="block yoda-div" id="yoda">
                <img src="yoda.png" alt="Yoda" class="image"  onmouseover="show()">
                <div class="text" onmouseout="hide()">That right, you got.
                    Herh herh herh.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="block" id="quote">
                <img src="quote1.jpg" alt="quote">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhilash pretty close to what I wanted. Now the hover text box is huge. Played around a little but can't figure out how to make it appear over Yoda in a much smaller box. :(

Comment: Hi Shire, I have updated my answer. Have a look. Thanks.

Comment: If it worked, please mark it as answer so that it is helpful for others.

Comment: Not sure I see that option  Abhilash. Sorry new here.

Comment: No the left of the answer, you will see up/down arrows and a TICK mark below it. Click on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello if I understood your question, this might be of help.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom-img {
  height: 45vh;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover
}

.sections {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.section-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 18px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sections">
      <div class="section-text">This is the left section</div>
     <img class="custom-img" src="https://slicedinvoices.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2015/12/better-urls.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="sections">
      <div class="section-text">This is right section</div>
     <img class="custom-img" src="https://yazoogle.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/urls.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

1. Move your quote1 div below the yoda img tag.

2.Modify your following css classes

```
.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    display: inline;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```